# Django ModelAdmin use custom query

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

Hi currently i'm having trouble add a custom ModelAdmin section to the app admin side without using any defined model in the models.py

For example i have 3 models(topups, withdrawals, transfers) and i would like to add a separate ModelAdmin transactions section that a combination from those 3 model, because i like it's paging, change listing and detail view.

My models:

```
#TOPUP
class TopUp(SafeDeleteModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "topups"
        verbose_name = 'TopUp Request'
        verbose_name_plural = 'TopUp Requests'

    user = models.ForeignKey("backend.User", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_toptup', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.ForeignKey("backend.Currency", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_topup_currency', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    TOPUP_METHOD_CHOICES = [
        (1, 'method 1'),
        (2, 'method 2')
    ]
    method = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Method", choices=TOPUP_METHOD_CHOICES)

    amount = models.DecimalField("Amount", max_digits=65, decimal_places=0, default=0)
    fee = models.DecimalField("Fee", max_digits=65, decimal_places=0, default=0)

    TOPUP_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (0, 'Pending'),
        (1, 'Success'),
        (2, 'Failed'),
    ]
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Status", choices=TOPUP_STATUS_CHOICES, default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    received = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

# WITHDRAWALS
class Withdrawals(SafeDeleteModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "withdrawals"
        verbose_name = 'Withdraw Request'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Withdraw Requests'

    user = models.ForeignKey("backend.User", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_withdrawal', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.ForeignKey("backend.Currency", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_withdrawal_currency', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    WITHDRAWAL_METHOD_CHOICES = [
        (1, 'method 1'),
        (2, 'method 2')
    ]
    method = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Method", choices=WITHDRAWAL_METHOD_CHOICES)
    to_bank = models.ForeignKey("backend.UserBank", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_withdrawal_userbank', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_column='to_bank')
    to_address = models.CharField("To address", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, db_column='to_address')
    to_card = models.ForeignKey("backend.CardBinding", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_withdrawal_to_card', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_column='to_card')
    amount = models.DecimalField("Amount", max_digits=65, decimal_places=0, default=0)
    fee = models.DecimalField("Fee", max_digits=65, decimal_places=0, default=0)

    WITHDRAWAL_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (0, 'Pending'),
        (1, 'success'),
        (2, 'failed')
    ]
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Status", choices=WITHDRAWAL_STATUS_CHOICES, default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    confirmed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

# TRANSFERS

class Transfers(SafeDeleteModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "transfers"
        verbose_name = 'Transfer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Transfers'

    user = models.ForeignKey("backend.User", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_transfer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.ForeignKey("backend.Currency", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_transfer_currency', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    TRANSFER_METHOD_CHOICES = [
        (2, 'method 1'),
        (3, 'method 2')
    ]
    method = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Method", choices=TRANSFER_METHOD_CHOICES)

    to_address = models.CharField("To Address", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, db_column='to_address')
    to_account = models.ForeignKey("backend.User", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_transfer_to_account', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_column='to_account')
    amount = models.DecimalField("Amount", max_digits=65, decimal_places=0, default=0)
    fee = models.DecimalField("Fee", max_digits=65, decimal_places=0, default=0)

    TRANSFER_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (0, 'Pending'),
        (1, 'Success'),
        (2, 'Failed')
    ]
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Status", choices=TRANSFER_STATUS_CHOICES, default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    confirmed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

So if i have a query for example like so:

```
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''
            SELECT * FROM 
                (SELECT id,
                    user_id, 
                    'top up'  AS transaction_type, 
                    method, 
                    NULL     AS to_bank, 
                    NULL     AS to_address, 
                    user_id  AS to_account, 
                    NULL     AS to_card, 
                    currency_id, 
                    amount, 
                    fee,
                    status, 
                    created AS created, 
                    received AS confirmed 
                FROM   topups 
                WHERE deleted IS NULL
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT id,
                    user_id, 
                    'transfer' AS transaction_type, 
                    method, 
                    NULL       AS to_bank, 
                    to_address, 
                    to_account, 
                    NULL       AS to_card, 
                    currency_id, 
                    amount, 
                    fee,
                    status, 
                    created AS created, 
                    confirmed  AS confirmed 
                FROM   transfers 
                WHERE deleted IS NULL
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT id,
                    user_id, 
                    'withdrawal' AS transaction_type, 
                    method, 
                    to_bank, 
                    to_address, 
                    NULL         AS to_account, 
                    to_card, 
                    currency_id, 
                    amount, 
                    fee,
                    status, 
                    created AS created, 
                    confirmed    AS confirmed 
                FROM   withdrawals
                WHERE deleted IS NULL
                ) AS T
            ORDER BY created DESC'''
        )

        row = namedtuplefetchall(cursor)
```

It return UNION of 3 tables and with columns like so:

```
  {
    "user_id": 120,
    "transaction_type": "transfer",
    "method": 3,
    "to_bank" null,
    "to_card" null,
    "to_address" null,
    "to_account": 170,
    "currency_id": 1,
    "amount": "-10000",
    "fee": "100000000",
    "status": 2,
    "created": 1582272307,
    "confirmed": 1582272307
  },
```

How do i make a ModelAdmin to use this query ? i haven't found any solution for admin section that use only raw query instead of model

Comment: Did you try overriding `get_queryset`?

Comment: i tried to make a proxy model of TopUp and use custom manager to return the query but i got key error of `user` on the admin listing page, i don't know if `get_queryset` accept RawQuery but i will try when i get home

Comment: I don't think you can use a RawQuery. But you might be able to use `ModelA.objects.all().union(ModelB.objects.all())`

Comment: that one way i tried in another question but i'm having problem with the annotate of string value as the post processing tried to parse int the string value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60732879/django-admin-annotate-string-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best experience (filtering, correct type detection) in `ModelAdmin` needs `Model` assigned.

Create `Model` with required fields. Tell Django not to manage the model - not to create db table for it - so it will assume db table for it already exists.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    # all fields of the result of UNION
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    method = models.IntegerField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False  # django will not create db table
        db_table = "myapp_transaction_view"  # if accessing database view
```

---

Now, you can either create [***database view***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createview.html) - fictional table in the database generated only when accessed - a shortcut for custom `SELECT`.

You can create django database migration and create view in it:

```
...
    migrations.RunSQL(
        """
        CREATE VIEW myapp_transaction_view AS
            SELECT * FROM .....; /* your UNION SELECT */
        """,
        """
        DROP VIEW IF EXISTS myapp_transaction_view;
        """,
    )
...
```

Now, `Transaction` model links to this view and selects from it run custom union select automatically. And this model can be just passed to `ModelAdmin` as usually.

---

Or, you can avoid creating view in the database - instead, redefine `get_queryset()` method on `ModelAdmin` and provide query in it - this way it may be more customizable or you can use Django ORM to build the query.

Further extending on this - custom sql can be placed in custom model manager as more proper place for sql / queryset than ModelAdmin.

Comment: Nice i can create an MySQL view from the query and use with with a fake model with `managed=false` and now i can act it as a model, thank for the suggestion. But because view does not has auto increment id the admin require an id primary key field, i will ask that in another question